# How to duplicate the upper observation value to lower obs based on condition?

Tags: r

Lets consider that there are three variables (A, B and c) in a dataset and now i need to create the variable D based on certain conditions. If B has Y, then the same value of C to be kept in variable D till the next Y appears.

```
A B  C   D (required output)
1 Y 10   10
2   11   10
3   2    10
4   5    10
5   8    10
6 Y 2    2
7   3    2
8   45   2
9 Y 1    1
10  0    1
```

Can you please help me to get the required output in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue can be solved using `fill()` from `tidyr` and `dplyr` functions:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df <- structure(list(A = 1:10, B = c("Y", "", "", "", "", "Y", "", 
"", "Y", ""), C = c(10L, 11L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 45L, 1L, 0L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

It looks like:

```
    A B  C
1   1 Y 10
2   2   11
3   3    2
4   4    5
5   5    8
6   6 Y  2
7   7    3
8   8   45
9   9 Y  1
10 10    0
```

You can create `D` with a condition based on `B` and then fill the missing values:

```
#Code
df %>% mutate(D=ifelse(B=='Y',C,NA)) %>%
  fill(D)
```

Output:

```
    A B  C  D
1   1 Y 10 10
2   2   11 10
3   3    2 10
4   4    5 10
5   5    8 10
6   6 Y  2  2
7   7    3  2
8   8   45  2
9   9 Y  1  1
10 10    0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `rep` + `rle` + `cumsum`

```
within(df,D <- rep(C[B=="Y"],rle(cumsum(B=="Y"))$lengths))
```

which gives

```
    A B  C  D
1   1 Y 10 10
2   2   11 10
3   3    2 10
4   4    5 10
5   5    8 10
6   6 Y  2  2
7   7    3  2
8   8   45  2
9   9 Y  1  1
10 10    0  1
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(A = 1:10, B = c("Y", "", "", "", "", "Y", "", 
"", "Y", ""), C = c(10L, 11L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 45L, 1L, 0L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use the index generated by the `cumsum` to replace the subset of values in 'C' to create the 'D' column

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
         mutate(D = C[B == "Y"][cumsum(B == "Y")])
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(A = 1:10, B = c("Y", "", "", "", "", "Y", "", 
"", "Y", ""), C = c(10L, 11L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 45L, 1L, 0L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```